# Apollo, AppSync, Warning about missing field

Tags: apollo, aws-appsync, apollo-link

I'm getting this warning:

```
backend.js:6 Missing field getCurrentConfigurations in [
{
  "id": "135631",
  "zone": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ZONA 1",
    "color": "#ba9b
```

It's a warning but my entire app has sometimes some weird behaviours. So I wonder how could fix those warnings. Apparently, the app works ok when I trigger a function that send that warning on chrome console, but I don't know why is happening.

[image]

I had to deal with an error about writing to cache some data, the solution in that case was adding an `id` value to each object and also a `__typename`

About the error and some solutions: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2510

About the same but with _`typename`: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1826

...but that's another story, anyway, that error occurs like 1 fro 20 times that I use the same function... it's all weird and random, but now I want to know if some one has a clue about the warning.

This is part of the code that shows what I'm using from Apollo

```
import AWSAppSyncClient, { createAppSyncLink, AUTH_TYPE } from 'aws-appsync';
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient(AppSyncConfig, {
  link: createAppSyncLink({ ...AppSyncConfig,
    resultsFetcherLink: ApolloLink.from([
      setContext((request, previousContext) => ({
        headers: { ...previousContext.headers,
          Authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') ? localStorage.getItem('token') : ''
        }
      })),
      createHttpLink({
        uri: AppSyncConfig.url
      })
    ])
  })
});
```

Comment: how are you adding the id?

Comment: At any level. I've tried that

Comment: can you provide your schema definition and the query for which this occurs?

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to add a link with code but SO doesn't let me